# Using python exchangelib, how to get total size of messages in mail folder

Tags: python, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I can iterate over all the mail folder using `for item in account.root.get_folders()` and `if item.__class__ == exchangelib.folders.Messages:` but how can I get the amount of space used by messages in that folder?

I've read online from that foldersize is a EWS extended property type, but how do I get that via exchangelib?
(FYI, the property is PropertyTag: 0x0e08;  PropertyType: Integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exchangelib` doesn't support extended properties on folders yet. EWS does expose a `size` attribute on items that could easily be added to `exchangelib` (feel free to open an issue:-)), which would allow you to do something like this:

```
sum(some_folder.all().values_list('size', flat=True))
```

**Update:**
Here is example code of using this to get folder size of all email (class folder.Message) folders:

```
for folder in account.root.find_folders():
  if folder.__class__ != exchangelib.folders.Messages:
      continue
  fsum = sum(folder.all().values_list('size', flat=True))
  print('{0:>40s} {1:12,d}'.format(folder.name.encode('utf-8'), fsum))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!